# Getting exception while calling ApplyWebConfigModifications for encoded url's as value

Tags: sharepoint, iis, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I am trying to update web.conig using powershell script for sharepoint web application using below code

```
$PublicWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://my_website                                                                  
$NewMod = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$NewMod.name = "add[@key='STSSignInURL']"
$NewMod.path = "/configuration/appSettings"
$NewMod.value =  "<add key='STSSignInURL' value='https://mydomain:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2ffra1fv-na%2f' />"
$NewMod.owner = "Owner"
$NewMod.sequence = 0
$NewMod.type = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification+SPWebConfigModificationType]::EnsureChildNode
$PublicWebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add($NewMod)
$PublicWebApp.Update()
$PublicWebApp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
```

But I am getting exception:

Exception calling "ApplyWebConfigModifications" with "0" argument(s): "=" is an unexpected token.

The value I am setting is an http encoded url, and I am facing this issue only with encoded url's. For other plain text's the code is working fine.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. The issue was with ampersand in "&wtrealm" using [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape() method resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Should the name of the mod be something like this:

```
$NewMod.name = "add[@key='STSSignInURL'][@value]='https://mydomain:443/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2ffra1fv-na%2f']"
```